# Need to Echo A Url path to show on a wordpress page

Tags: php, functions, shortcode, urls

I need to extract a url path number to a shortcode... Here is an example below...

https://example.com/page/c/1

I need the number "1" to be shown with a shortcode...

[url_path_number]

Comment: You get all values from an URL via `$_REQUEST` or `$_GET`. However I think this value integer is the ID of a post, page or similar in your WP install, so that you can use the WP core function like `get_the_ID`.

Answer (score 0):

You can find that with somthing like the following

```
add_shortcode( 'url_path_number', function ( $atts ) {

    // use an attribute or the current URL
    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'url' => get_permalink(),
    ), $atts );

    // get the path from the URL
    $path = parse_url($a['url'],PHP_URL_PATH);
    $parts = array_filter(explode('/', $path),function($v) { return $v !== ''; });

    // get the last dir of path
    return end($parts); 
} );
```

Using the shortcode will return current URL

```
[url_path_number]
```

or you can specify the URL

```
[url_path_number url="https://example.com/page/c/1"]
```

---

### UPDATE:

to go just after the path, and not use `get_permalink()`

```
add_shortcode( 'url_path_number', function ( $atts ) {
    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'path' => $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],
    ), $atts );
    $parts = array_filter(explode('/',$a['path']),function($v) { return $v !== ''; });
    return end($parts); 
} );
```

Comment: Is it possible to add this to the url instead of get_permalink... <?php 
$Path=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
echo $URI='https://example.com'.$Path;
?>

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect going after just the path, without `get_permalink()`

Comment: the update code is awfully insecure.. You should never use an input variable without validation, or at the minimum escape it when returning the result.